# Как спарсить данные поиска с сайта майкрасофт? https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/search

Tags: javascript, json, парсер

При получении ответа на гет запрос я получаю его без ссылок и результатов поиска, как решить проблему?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вычислил такой запрос например на тему JavaScript:

```
https://docs.microsoft.com/api/search?search=JavaScript&locale=ru-ru
```

Возвращает JSON.

Comment: А что ели мне нужно парсить конкретно по определенному ключу или это не проблема? Просто при сравнении результатов поиска и результатов RSS ленты - они вообще разные

Comment: RSS действительно выдаёт ерунду